# Convert single font character into bitmap pixel array in c++

Tags: c++, fonts, bitmap, windows-ce

I have a problem converting a character into a bitmap pixel array.

I work with Windows CE 6 and I have written an application in C++ to manage an OLED by serial interface.

To display the image on OLED I use the bitmap format, then if I want to display a text on OLED I have to convert the character to a bitmap array first, but I don't know how take a single character from a Windows CE font and convert it into a bitmap pixel array (bytes)  to send it out via the serial interface.

Have you got an idea (standard functions, custom functions etc) how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

[`CreateDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms959931.aspx) to create a device context.
[`CreateCompatibleBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms959927.aspx) to create a bitmap of the right size.
[`SelectObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms961438.aspx) to select the bitmap into the DC.
[`CreateFontIndirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms959955.aspx) to create font.
[`SelectObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms961438.aspx) to select the font into the DC.
[`DrawText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms960231.aspx) to draw the character on the DC.
[`SelectObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms961438.aspx) to select the previously selected bitmap back into the DC.
[`SelectObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms961438.aspx) to select the previously selected font back into the DC.
[`DeleteObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms960030.aspx) to delete the created font.
[`DeleteDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms960023.aspx) to delete the DC.

You now have a bitmap with the letter.